# how do I obtain every hundredth row per ID in a dataset? SAS

Tags: statistics, sas, sas-macro, do-loops

I have a list of 10000 observations, 1000 per code number (ID):

```
proc surveyselect data=code_nums out=bootstrapped_code_names (keep=code_name qty replicate) sampsize=1825 method=urs outhits no print seed=0 rep=1000;
strata code_num;
run;

proc sql no print;
create table test as 
select code_num
,replicate
,sum(quantity) as total_qty
from bootstrapped_code_names
group code_name
order by total_qty

quit;
```

To get this:

```
data work.code;
input code_num $9. replicate total_qty;
datalines;
123456780 87   0
123456780 34   0
12345678  837  2
123456780 475  4
123456780 74   5
123456780 507  9
123456780 28   9
123456788 76   3
```

I would like to obtain a dataset that captures every hundredth observation for every ID, to get something like this:

| id | replicate | qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 174 | 54 |
| 12345 | 56 | 76 |
| 12345 | 876 | 98 |
| 12345 | 354 | 102 |
| 12345 | 7 | 106 |
| 12345 | 45 | 113 |
| 12345 | 128 | 123 |
| 12345 | 23 | 156 |
| 12345 | 948 | 168 |
| 12347 | 465 | 24 |
| 12347 | 374 | 36 |
| 12347 | 58 | 55 |
| 12347 | 38 | 78 |
| 12347 | 11 | 109 |
| 12347 | 283 | 117 |
| 12345 | 90 | 133 |
| 12345 | 23 | 145 |
| 12345 | 948 | 160 |

and so on for each ID.

I tried this code by it doesn't apply for distinct ID:

```
%macro test;
  %do j=10 %to 90 %by 10;
  %global row&j.;
  %let row&j. = %sysevalf(1000*&j./100, floor);
%end;
%mend test;

data get_rows;
set code;
if _N_ in(&row&10., &row&20., &row&30., &row&40., &row&50., &row&60., &row&70., &row&80., &row&90.);
run;

data _null_;
set get_rows;
row = _N_*10;
call symputx('row' ||strip(row), replicate, 'G');
run;
```

How can get every hundred row per ID? Each ID has 1000 rows.

Comment: You should mark your questions as answered.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I follow your full problem description, but here is simple code to select the first, 101st, 201st, etc observation per ID value. The source data must already be sorted by the ID variable(s).

```
data want;
  do _n_=1 by 1 until(last.id);
    set have;
    by id;
    if 1=mod(_n_,100) then output;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you, I would like the 100th, 200th, etc observation per ID value. Would I change the _ni_=1 to 0. I do not want to include the first observation for each ID. @Tom

Comment: If you want the 100th then use `0=`.  If you want the 50th then use `50=`.  You can use any number between 0 and 99.  For the special case of zero you could do `if not mod(_n_,100) ...` since 0 is false and any other non missing value is true.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the code from yesterday by using a MOD function to check if the value is divisible by 100. Change the value in the MOD function to get other values.

https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/vdmmlcdc/8.1/ds2ref/n0t9j8b09x4uphn1kl1i70x63z19.htm

```
data work.code;
input code_num $9. replicate total_qty;
datalines;
123456780 87   0
123456780 34   0
123456780  837  2
123456780 475  4
123456780 74   5
123456780 507  9
123456780 28   9
123456780 87   0
123456780 34   0
123456780  837  2
123456780 475  4
123456780 74   5
123456780 507  9
123456780 28   9
123456788 76   3
123456788 76   3
123456788 76   3
123456788 76   3
123456788 76   3
;;;;


data code_counter;
set code;
by code_num;

if first.code_num then count=1;
else count+1;
run;

data code100;
set code_counter;
if mod(count, 100)=0 then output;
run;
```